# Impossible to convert a whole list of list into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use Pycharm and I would like to convert my list of list as an array. 
I have a list that contains 3992 elements and each one contains 526 elements. 
So

```
len(list_of_list)=3297 & 
len(list_of_list[0])=len(list_of_list[1])=...=len(list_of_list[3297])=526
```

In order to convert I did

```
import numpy as np
list_to_array=np.array(list_of_list)
```

As outuput I'd like to get a shape of (3297,526)

```
list_of_list.shape = (3297,526)
```

However I don't know why when I run the code I get an output of

```
list_of_list.shape = (3297,)
```

Comment: I suspect that your sublists are *not* actually equal-length. That would cause the behavior you are seeing. Otherwise, if they were, they should result in what you want.

Comment: also, check `list_of_list.dtype`. If it is `object` i.e `dtype('O')` then it is a strong indicator that is what is happening.

Comment: As a tip, remember that since your expected result *is* the expected result for a list of lists, so you are going to need to give more information about your list of lists if you want help. How are you sure that every subelement has 526 items?

Comment: How can a list containing 3992 elements have length 3297 and why do you expect a shape with 3287? Shouldn't those three numbers all be the same? And how can you use index 3297 when the length is only 3297?

Comment: @StefanPochmann that is a good point. I am *assuming* that was a typo.

Comment: You are right I checked my sublists have not the same size.

Comment: @StefanPochmann it's a typing error, all my sublist have the same size, i don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

The sublists of your list "list_of_list" are not equal-length which means not every sublist contains 526 elements.

Try the following code to find out the line with different length:

```
for i in range(list_of_list):
    if len(list_of_list[i]) != 526:
        print i
```